# Esc and Shift not giving Grub menu in 18.04.1

Tags: boot, grub2, 18.04

I have installed 18.04.1 from DVD with no other OS on computer.  No Grub menu appears and system sticks after "Ubuntu" screen appears, with no pointer or other movement.  Trying to boot into recovery mode with either <kbd>Esc</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd> does not bring up Grub.  Obviously I can't use Terminal to do anything to the OS.  No problem with 16.04.